# How to edit a rugarch package function?

Tags: r, function, debugging

I'm trying to understand how some 'rugarch' package r functions work; in order to do that, I would like to access such functions.

I tryed to access them by running, for the case of the 'ugarchsim' function:

```
trace(ugarchsim,edit=TRUE)
```

but I got only the function specification with the following output:

> ```
> function (fit, n.sim = 1000, n.start = 0, m.sim = 1, startMethod = c("unconditional", 
>   "sample"), presigma = NA, prereturns = NA, preresiduals = NA, 
> rseed = NA, custom.dist = list(name = NA, distfit = NA), 
> mexsimdata = NULL, vexsimdata = NULL, ...) 
> standardGeneric("ugarchsim")
> ```

The same thing does not happen for other kind of function, as, for instance, the `lm()` function.
Anyone knows how to access such kind of functions?

For instance, in the case of the `lm` function, one gets:

> ```
> function (formula, data, subset, weights, na.action, method = "qr", 
> model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE, singular.ok = TRUE, 
> contrasts = NULL, offset, ...) 
> {
> ret.x <- x
> ret.y <- y
> cl <- match.call()
> mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
> m <- match(c("formula", "data", "subset", "weights", "na.action", 
>     "offset"), names(mf), 0L)
> mf <- mf[c(1L, m)]
> mf$drop.unused.levels <- TRUE
> mf[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)
> mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())
> if (method == "model.frame") 
> return(mf)
> else if (method != "qr") 
> warning(gettextf("method = '%s' is not supported. Using 'qr'", 
> method), domain = NA)
> mt <- attr(mf, "terms")
> y <- model.response(mf, "numeric")
> w <- as.vector(model.weights(mf))
> if (!is.null(w) && !is.numeric(w)) 
> stop("'weights' must be a numeric vector")
> offset <- model.offset(mf)
> mlm <- is.matrix(y)
> ny <- if (mlm) 
> nrow(y)
> else length(y)
> if (!is.null(offset)) {
> if (!mlm) 
> offset <- as.vector(offset)
> if (NROW(offset) != ny) 
> stop(gettextf("number of offsets is %d, should equal %d (number of observations)", 
> NROW(offset), ny), domain = NA)
>   }
> if (is.empty.model(mt)) {
> x <- NULL
> z <- list(coefficients = if (mlm) matrix(NA_real_, 0, 
> ncol(y)) else numeric(), residuals = y, fitted.values = 0 * 
> y, weights = w, rank = 0L, df.residual = if (!is.null(w)) sum(w != 
> 0) else ny)
> if (!is.null(offset)) {
> z$fitted.values <- offset
> z$residuals <- y - offset
>     }
>   }
> else {
> x <- model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)
> z <- if (is.null(w)) 
> lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, 
>         ...)
> else lm.wfit(x, y, w, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, 
>       ...)
>   }
> class(z) <- c(if (mlm) "mlm", "lm")
> z$na.action <- attr(mf, "na.action")
> z$offset <- offset
> z$contrasts <- attr(x, "contrasts")
> z$xlevels <- .getXlevels(mt, mf)
> z$call <- cl
> z$terms <- mt
> if (model) 
> z$model <- mf
> if (ret.x) 
> z$x <- x
> if (ret.y) 
> z$y <- y
> if (!qr) 
> z$qr <- NULL
> z
> }
> ```

Is it possible to get what the 'ugarchsim' function actually does as for the 'lm' function?